# Display a range of values between two user input values between two different columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, between

For example: table name = table

### column1 | column2

```
1              7
2              8
3              9
4             NULL
5              11
6              12
```

A user is asked to enter two values, one from column1 and one from column 2. Lets say user enters 2 and 12. the result should look something like this.

### column1 | column2

```
3              9
4             NULL
5              11
```

I have tried by using this code below but i'm not sure if it works correctly. Plus Null values are not shown so that's a problem too. Also, actual values contain both numeric and string values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 
FROM table 
WHERE column1 
BETWEEN '&column1' AND column1 
AND column2 NOT BETWEEN '&column2 AND column2 
ORDER BY column1;
```

Thank you for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 
FROM table 
WHERE column1 
BETWEEN '&column1' AND (SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = '&column2') 
ORDER BY column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN denotes non-strict inequality. If you don't want rows

```
2 8
6 12
```

to appear in result, you'll have to write

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2
FROM table
WHERE (column1 > '&column1' or column1 is null) 
  AND (column2 < '&column2' or column2 is null)
ORDER BY column1;
```

Comment: Thank for the information. But what i was looking for, was to display rows depending on both input values together. the answer above was perfect.